# Checking if any strings in one list are a substring in another list

Tags: python

I know that if I just have two strings that checking using `x in y` will work.  And that if I just wanted to check if a string is in any of the strings in a list I'd just use a `for` loop for that.

But what is the most pythonic/efficient way to check if any of the strings in the first list are substrings of the strings in the second list?

An example would be:

```
notPresent = []
present = []
listA = ['Rick', 'James']
listB = ['Rick', 'Ricky', 'Ryan', 'Jam', 'Jamesses', 'Jamboree']

notPresent = ['Ryan', 'Jam', 'Jamboree']
present = ['Rick', 'Ricky', 'Jamesses']
```

I'm going to use both `present` and `notPresent` words.

Comment: *"check if any of"* - [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)? Do you have current code that you think is unpythonic and/or inefficient?

Comment: Any as in "any of the elements of the list".  I'm in the process of figuring out how to do this, not optimise existing code.  I'm guessing a for loop within a for loop.

Comment: Yes, I understand, and I'm saying *there's a built-in function for that*. Follow the link and have a look!

Comment: Did you downvote me because I awarded the answer to the person that gave it to me?  You don't provide any answer or assistance, and then downvote me and negatively comment the answerer?!?!

Comment: 1. I did provide assistance. 2. I didn't *"negatively comment the answerer"*, I gave them some constructive feedback. 3. Whether I or anyone else downvoted and why is pretty much none of your business. FWIW, I would have liked to have seen some *actual effort to implement this on your part*.

Comment: 3.  I was just curious of the reasoning anyone would downvote this question.  It's understandable if there's actually something wrong with it.  Otherwise I'd wonder what the motivation could be.

Comment: @johnrsharpe, I looked at [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), but don't understand how this would help McLeodx with his problem. Could you elaborate? loop through lists with testing and creating new lists with true / false? Or can [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) do something I don't see?

Comment: @SebastiaanMannem there are already two answers showing ways to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say something like this:

```
#python2
notPresent = set()
present = set()
listA = ['Rick', 'James']
listB = ['Rick', 'Ricky', 'Ryan', 'Jam', 'Jamesses', 'Jamboree']

#notPresent = ['Ryan','Jam','Jamboree']
#present = ['Rick','Ricky','Jamesses']

for b in listB:
  for a in listA:
    if a in b:
      present.add(b)
      break
  else:
    notPresent.add(b)

print(list(notPresent))
print(list(present))
```

So basically 2 for loops. And use sets instead of lists (fr uniqueness of values)...

Comment: *Why* would you say something like that? Could you add some explanation? One obvious issue is that you continue to scan `listA` even after the item is matched.

Comment: I fixed the scanning after matching. The reason I would do it like this, is because it's a clear and readable aprach of the problem (scanning through a list by items of another list, looks like 2 for loops to me). 
Given that you want to do something for every element of listB, after scannin listA, I found it clear to put the for loop of listB in the outer ring.
And sets look more clear, since they only store a value ones and you want only the element once. However, with the break, lists work just as well (I assmume)...

Comment: 1. Please put that explanation *in the answer*. 2. That's a minimal fix, note that the `for: else:` construct would remove the (somewhat unpythonic) flag you have now.

Comment: This actually delivered the correct result without the edit you made as well.  Cheers Sebastiaan.  I'll use the version with the break though.

Comment: @mcleodx: great ;). Cheers to you too.

Comment: @johnrsharpe: About 1: I'll try to do that in the future. However, for now, I already added it as a comment, and it seems a bit foolish to put it down twice, right?
About 2: Thanks, I added your suggestion to my sollution and it keeps getting better.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) comprehension:

```
listA = ['Rick', 'James']
listB = ['Rick', 'Ricky', 'Ryan', 'Jam', 'Jamesses', 'Jamboree']

present = {i for i in listB if any(j in i for j in listA)}
notPresent = set(listB) - present  # difference of two sets 

print(present)
# {'Rick', 'Ricky', 'Jamesses'}

print(notPresent)
# {'Jamboree', 'Ryan', 'Jam'}
```

`any` helps avoid running the entire length of the iteration after a match has been found, and with `set` you can generate the complementary set `notPresent` from the first.

Answer (score 1):

the fastest way is probably to turn the first list into a set

```
setA = set(listA)
```

then, for each string in `listB`, check if any of its substrings are in `setA`.

```
def substrings(s):
    for i in range len(s)
        for j in range i
            yield s[i:j]

result = []
for s in listB:
    if any(substring in setA for substring in substrings(s)):
        result.append(s)
```

Comment: remember to lowercase the strings first

Comment: if you want to get more fancy, look up "suffix array datastructure"