# Is there a way to check if strings in a list contain any substrings from another list?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of strings, list_1 and list_2.

```
list_1 = ["Hello", "Hi", "Hey"]
list_2 = ["Hello, my name in John.", "Hi, my name is John.", "Hey, my name 
           is John.", "My name is John."]
```

I want to check if any of the strings in list_1 are contained in any of the strings in  list_2, in such a way that returns the strings in list_2 for which this is true. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Already tried something yourself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to check if a value exist in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exist-in-a-list)

Comment: Not clear what you are expecting to get as an output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do not delete your question when you get your answer. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378440/caveat-emptor-making-students-aware-they-cannot-delete-their-homework-questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/38158577/13968392

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `any` function with a generator expression as a filter condition of a list comprehension:

```
[s for s in list_2 if any(k in s for k in list_1)]
```

This returns:

```
['Hello, my name in John.', 'Hi, my name is John.', 'Hey, my name is John.']
```